# Getting data from password protected website via requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm a freelance editor in my spare time, but recently the company I work for made their notification system MUCH worse, causing me to miss out on a lot of opportunities. I decided I'd try to create a simple python script to pull the website every minute or so, check for changes in a specific field, and send an email to a dedicated account to notify me. I've never used python, but I got stuck in and found that the best option is probably the `requests` library. I'm having difficulty getting the right page with authentication, though, as all my requests just lead to the log in page.

The site works like this (I'm missing the TLD in case it gets flagged as spam):

1. The employee heads to whiteboard.cactusglobal
2. They log in and are sent to whiteboard.cactusglobal/dashboard, which has the field I want to read.

I've tried the following:

```
requests.get('https://whiteboard.cactusglobal.com/dashboard', auth=('user','pass'))
```

where *user* and *pass* are replaced with the appropriate values, but no dice. I've also tried

```
requests.get('https://whiteboard.cactusglobal.com/dashboard', auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user','pass'))
```

which didn't help, and

```
payload = {'user':'XXXXXXXX', 'pass':'XXXXXXX'}
requests.post('https://whiteboard.cactusglobal.com/dashboard', data=payload})
```

which still didn't work. As mentioned, all requests give a 403 and return the login page.

I've used Burp to capture the `POST` request with my login details from my browser, in hopes it might shed some light on the problem, but I don't know enough about how `requests` works to do anything. Here's the request (with cookies removed):

```
POST /dashboard?destination=dashboard HTTP/1.1
Host: whiteboard.cactusglobal.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://whiteboard.cactusglobal.com/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 125
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
name=XXXXXXXX&pass=XXXXXXXXXX&form_build_id=XXXXXXXXXX&form_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I'm sorry to ask for help with something that could be easily Googled if I understood it better, but with my lack of knowledge of python and minimal knowledge of HTTP requests there's too many unknowns for me to be able to grasp the problem effectively. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried setting the "User-Agent" field as the json you can supply to the header formal parameter?

Comment: I've tried setting the User-Agent to Mozilla/5.0 to make sure the request wasn't being blocked because of that, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Then I don't know. Their robots.txt looks pretty restrictive, is it possible they are blocking that user-agent / IP by now?

Comment: Is once a minute really necessary? If the company notices that you're pinging their website hundreds of times a day, they might not like that.

Comment: Working in freelance, jobs are offered up to like 50 appropriate editors at once and it's fastest finger first. Once a minute seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it has nothing to do with `python` or HTTP requests.
The site `whiteboard.cactusglobal` is not an API, it is a website.
It is not meant to able you to access its page only programatically. It expects a real user that interacts with it thanks to its browser.

So for me, the tool that you need is [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Or any User Testing Automation tool, really. That kind of tools will let you emulate a browser that goes to the website, is redirected to the log page, and enter the authentification information in the relevant fields, all within Python.

As your use-case is basic, if you understand the basic tutorials, in particular how to fill forms, you will easily find your way :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried Selenium and it's really simple and intuitive. Great solution!

Comment: @Plesbien Can you share the solution? I need.